# VS Code Remote-Containers: cannot create directory ‘/home/appuser’:

Tags: visual-studio-code, dockerfile, vscode-remote

I'm trying to use the [Remote - Containers extension](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/containers) for Visual Studio Code, but when I "Open Folder in Container", I get this error:

```
Run: docker exec 0d0c1eac6f38b81566757786f853d6f6a4f3a836c15ca7ed3a3aaf29b9faab14 /bin/sh -c set -o noclobber ; mkdir -p '/home/appuser/.vscode-server/data/Machine' && { > '/home/appuser/.vscode-server/data/Machine/.writeMachineSettingsMarker' ; } 2> /dev/null
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘/home/appuser’: Permission denied
```

My Dockerfile uses:

```
FROM python:3.7-slim
...
RUN useradd -ms /bin/bash appuser
USER appuser
```

I've also tried:

```
RUN adduser -D appuser
RUN groupadd -g 999 appuser && \
    useradd -r -u 999 -g appuser appuser
USER appuser
```

Both of these work if I build them directly. How do I get this to work?

Comment: Did you ever find an answer to this question @43Tesseracts ?

Comment: Nope, I gave up on it.

Comment: I started a bounty to draw attention to this. The docs from Microsoft is not helping

Comment: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/containers-advanced#_avoiding-extension-reinstalls-on-container-rebuild

Answer (score 3):

What works for me is to create a non-root user in my Dockerfile and then configure the VS Code dev container to use that user.

Step 1. Create the non-root user in your Docker image

```
ARG USER_ID=1000
ARG GROUP_ID=1000
RUN groupadd --system --gid ${GROUP_ID} MY_GROUP && \
    useradd --system --uid ${USER_ID} --gid MY_GROUP --home /home/MY_USER --shell /sbin/nologin MY_USER
```

Step 2. Configure `.devcontainer/devcontainer.json` file in the root of your project (should be created when you start remote dev)

```
"remoteUser": "MY_USER" <-- this is the setting you want to update
```

If you use docker compose, it's possible to configure VS Code to run the entire container as the non-root user by configuring `.devcontainer/docker-compose.yml`, but I've been happy with the process described above so I haven't experimented further.

You might get some additional insight by reading through the [VS Code docs](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/containers) on this topic.

Comment: just to clarify, you add the user in your docker file

Comment: @magicsign yes, in the Dockerfile

Answer (score 0):

go into your WSL2 and check what is your local uid (non-root) using command id.
in my case it is UID=1000(ubuntu).
Change your dockerfile, to something like this:

```
# For more information, please refer to https://aka.ms/vscode-docker-python
FROM python:3.8-slim-buster

# Keeps Python from generating .pyc files in the container
ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE=1

# Turns off buffering for easier container logging
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1

# Install pip requirements
COPY requirements.txt .
RUN python -m pip install -r requirements.txt



WORKDIR /home/ubuntu
COPY . /home/ubuntu

# Creates a non-root user and adds permission to access the /app folder
# For more info, please refer to https://aka.ms/vscode-docker-python-configure-containers
RUN useradd -u 1000 ubuntu && chown -R ubuntu /home/ubuntu
USER ubuntu


# During debugging, this entry point will be overridden. For more information, please refer to https://aka.ms/vscode-docker-python-debug
CMD ["python", "app.py"]
```